# How do I adjust maxheight in tippy.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I dont know how to adjust heigh of tooltips from tippy.js

Coulnt find way to acces it there must be some easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from source code tippy.js uses this style sheet:

```css
.tippy-box[data-animation=fade][data-state=hidden] {
  opacity: 0
}

[data-tippy-root] {
  max-width: calc(100vw - 10px)
}

.tippy-box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  white-space: normal;
  outline: 0;
  transition-property: transform, visibility, opacity
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=top]>.tippy-arrow {
  bottom: 0
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=top]>.tippy-arrow:before {
  bottom: -7px;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 8px 8px 0;
  border-top-color: initial;
  transform-origin: center top
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=bottom]>.tippy-arrow {
  top: 0
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=bottom]>.tippy-arrow:before {
  top: -7px;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px;
  border-bottom-color: initial;
  transform-origin: center bottom
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=left]>.tippy-arrow {
  right: 0
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=left]>.tippy-arrow:before {
  border-width: 8px 0 8px 8px;
  border-left-color: initial;
  right: -7px;
  transform-origin: center left
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=right]>.tippy-arrow {
  left: 0
}

.tippy-box[data-placement^=right]>.tippy-arrow:before {
  left: -7px;
  border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
  border-right-color: initial;
  transform-origin: center right
}

.tippy-box[data-inertia][data-state=visible] {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.54, 1.5, .38, 1.11)
}

.tippy-arrow {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  color: #333
}

.tippy-arrow:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid
}

.tippy-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  z-index: 1
}
```

So you can try mess with that, adding your overrides, *but* it would be far better just to use a `div` with `max-height` as the content you provide for the tooltip and tippy.js will adjust itself.

```js
var html = "<div class='text-center' style='max-height:200px'>I'm a <b>Tippy</b> tooltip!<br><a>link</a></div>"

var instance = tippy(elems, {
  content: html,
  allowHTML: true,
});
```

Comment: I alredy knew that but you made me reailse where i had the problem so big thanks,you saved me so bad!